# Cсылка со значениями из инпутов

Tags: html, php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть страница, на ней несколько инпутов (name1, name2, name3...), в них пользователь записывает значения, типа "123". Требуется снизу добавить несколько ссылок на различные страницы (page1, page2, page3...), чтобы у страниц в конце были дописаны значения инпутов. Выражаясь языком дилетанта:

```
page1.php?a=value-name1&a=value-name2&a=value-name3
```

строить форму не подходит, т.к. ссылки не на одну, а на разные страницы.

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как на Яндексе? =)

```
$('input.word').keyup = function(){
    var str = '?';
    $('input.word').each(function(){str += '&'+this.name+'='+this.value});
    $('a.link').each(function(){this.href = this.href.split('php')[0] + 'php' + str;});
}
```

input.word - инпуты, в которые пишутся значения
a.link - изменяемые сслыки
И да, нужна jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='page1.php' id='page1'>page1</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#page1').click(function(){
var href = "page1.php?";
$('input').each(function(index){
  href += $(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val();
});
window.location = href;
});
</script>
```

Comment: интересная конструкция. странно, но у меня не сработало. идет простой переход на page1.php без переменных в строчке адреса.
 - а есть подобное решение без javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Впишите несколько форм:

```
<form action="page1" name="name1" method="post"><input name="name1"></form>
<form action="page2" name="name2 method="post""><input name="name2"></form>
<form action="page3" name="name3 method="post""><input name="name3"></form>
```

PS а почему вы уверены, что пользователь будет вписывать "123", а не какую-нибудь херь, типа sql-injection?

Comment: Sql-injection будет обрабатываться на сервере, а js можно портить как угодно - себе дороже.

Comment: Уважаемый, можно про "хрень" по подробнее объяснить? желательно с примерами и "хреновыми" вытекающими последствиями

Comment: я имею ввиду. что если то, что пользователь "должен" вводить то, что определено заранее типа: 123,проще эти поля заранее прописать не в поле: text, а в поле: "radio" или "select"